# Android: is it possible to draw line over a webview?

Tags: android

I am loading an html in android webview. The HTML has a big-image only.
Now, is it possible to draw line through android code over it!

The image is bigger than android screen. Then how will i get co-ordinates of out-screen image!

Comment: Could you draw a picture of what you want exactly?

Comment: I want to deal with both webview & appview.